# Is there any correlation between energy consumption and scientific progress?

Tags: climate-change, technology, society, science, sustainable-development

I was just thinking of an unconventional argument that if (hypothetically) cutting carbon emissions could slow down an economy if it meant there was less access to energy and hence less general societal productivity, that it could be more effective to avert climate issues by allowing the continued use of fossil fuels, while this energy resource is available, but focus on developing technologies in general that would not only lead to a generally more advanced and prosperous society, including advances in equality, education, healthcare, etc., but also lead to scientific breakthroughs which could reduce climate problems in various ways (carbon zero energy sources, carbon sequestration and climate engineering, etc.)

Is there any strong, rigorous argument that the more energy a society has, the generally better it becomes - more prosperous, with a higher rate of development, and hence, with a larger intellectual class to fuel breakthroughs in science and technology? Or is this false?

Comment: How do you quantify "scientific progress"?  Number of people with STEM degrees? Number of patents granted?  Number of Nobel Prizes?  (Per capita.)

Comment: [Energy consumption numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_energy_consumption_per_capita) are easier to find.

Comment: without sustainability - the more developed a society is, the more it consumes or exports (based on GDP definition). The causation seems opposite.

Comment: This is likely a better fit for History SE, where it can be answered objectively over the last several thousand years (yes, there is a correlation; no, there is not a correlation) as opposed to using not objective measures over a likely tiny timespan (100 years).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network (History SE).

Comment: The premise that a "better society" is a "more prosperous" one with a "higher rate of development" and a "larger intellectual class" is highly subjective.

Comment: Voting to close - I agree with uberhaxed that this Q is not suitable here.

Answer (score 6):

The title asked for a correlation and if you compare different countries a correlation clearly exists. Both energy consumption and technological progress correlate with wealth and current level of technology (it is much easier to progress beyond the current state of the art if you are at the current state of the art).

But this is also a classic example where correlation doesn't imply causation. Trying to increase energy consumption in the hope of speeding technological progress easily leads to ideas for completely nonsensical policy proposals like forcing lower efficency heating technologies.

Answer (score 3):

This would be true for a communist society that can actively direct resource expenditure.

Within a market economy, all of these developments are contingent on either someone making the determination that this will yield greater rewards than the cost (including opportunity cost of not pursuing other strategies), or someone making a decision that is not based on economical thinking.

Bluntly speaking, as long as fossil fuels are available, society will not focus its efforts without a market intervention, and with the unbalanced distribution of money, a purely market-based approach to fossil fuel reduction will also reduce productivity before it will reduce waste -- a higher carbon price will make people stop heating their home, while billionaires still fly private jets.

Fossil fuels are stored solar energy (almost all available energy is solar energy!), and there is a conversion cost between radiation, chemical, thermal, mechanical and electrical energy. Using fossil fuels for heating is one conversion, generating electricity off that is another.

Returning the ecosystem to its previous state means returning that energy back into storage, which again has conversion losses. Just extracting CO₂ and storing it somewhere does not make much of a dent in air composition, because the oxygen is still bound to the carbon, and unbinding it requires energy.

So basically using fossil fuels is a high-interest loan from the future. This can make sense if the expected return is higher, which is often the case for infrastructure investments, but it would have to be coupled with the necessary controlling that spending is goal-oriented.

To answer your question: having lots of energy available leads to a more prosperous society, but it also makes that society dependent on the continued availability of that energy. Over a longer time period, "continued" means "sustainable."

For the society to stay prosperous, it needs to self-organize into sustainability, and that is not an automatic process.

Answer (score 2):

> **Question:**
>
> Is there any correlation between energy consumption and scientific progress?

**Short Answer:**

Traditionally absolutely, but that is not hard rule.  As priorities change so can the correlations.  Right now the world has decided they need to investigate conserving energy, reducing greenhouse gasses and science can help with those things too.  So even now some of the most advanced countries are investing in cleaner renewable technology and showing cutting green house gasses and energy consumption in the 21st century can also be a sign of scientific progress.

**Longer Answer:**

Traditionally yes, and yes that is a concern.

> **[Role of Energy and Economic Growth in India](https://unacademy.com/content/ssc/study-material/general-awareness/role-of-energy-and-economic-growth-in-india)**
>
> Energy makes people's lives easier. Hence, their productivity also increases. Increase in energy generation and supply not only accelerates economic growth but also improves the living standards of people.

When economists try to gage economic activity one of the indicators traditionally is energy consumption.  So yeah, traditionally the amount of carbon and energy produced does have a correlation between economic activity and by the principles of economics, scientific progress.

In Adam Smith's **Wealth of Nations** he describes not only how industrialization works.  But how to spend the profits made through the new more efficient industrialized manufacturing system rather than the former trade craft manufacturing system.  He hypothesized that the true wealth of nations was in what they produced, not in how much gold they had in the bank.  He advised that the smartest use of profits from this method was to roll them back into the business in order to produce your widgets more efficiently.  If you don't your competition certainly will, and they will replace you.

> **[Wealth of Nations Org](https://www.adamsmith.org/the-wealth-of-nations)**
>
> Smith goes on to say that building up capital is an essential condition for economic progress. By saving some of what we produce instead of immediately consuming it, we can invest in new, dedicated, labour-saving equipment. The more we invest, the more efficient our production becomes. It is a virtuous circle.

Those funds dedicated to producing widgets more efficiently gave rise to the Industrial Revolution, and modern science.  So yes in the 18th, 19th and 20th centuries energy equated to greater production and greater production meant greater investment in science.  This association gave us the steam engine, gasoline engine, and electric engines as the industrialized countries competed to automate in a never ending competition of efficiency.

What's missing from analysis is given green house gas and global warming entirely new fields of science are springing up to curb such emissions.  As countries put more and more effort into them one would expect the most advanced countries which pursue these large scale reform to curb their green house gasses.   It's already happening many countries in Europe, North America and Asia are making progress and cutting or at least curbing significantly green house gas emissions and in these cases it's the dearth  of such emissions which demonstrate scientific progress.

**[Germany’s emissions hit 70-year low as it reduces reliance on coal](https://www.theguardian.com/business/2024/jan/04/germany-emissions-hit-70-year-low-reduces-reliance-coal)**

Answer (score 1):

### Carbon Emissions and Economic Activity are *Not* Linked

US [GDP](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/GDP) has grown steadily for the last several decades.

US [CO2 Emissions](https://www.epa.gov/ghgemissions/inventory-us-greenhouse-gas-emissions-and-sinks) peaked nearly 20 years ago, in 2007.

Thus the last 2 decades of economic growth with declining CO2 emissions show that it is possible to have a robust economy while cutting emissions.

Comment: This question appears to be about scientific progress, not economic prosperity. In addition, cherry picking 20 recent years for an anomalous country when their are hundreds of countries and thousands of years to analyze doesn't pass rigor for supporting your conclusion. Also, GDP is not a good proxy for "economic activity". For example, let's pretend that we both have kids. Taking care of our kids is a lot of work, but not captured in GDP. However, if were to take care of each other's kids and pay each other equal amounts, this activity is added to GDP, even though nothing has changed.

Comment: @codemonkey,  The US has also shifted away from manufacturing in favor of cheaper outsourcing  options,  and shifted to a service oriented economy.

Comment: @uberhaxed - OP is proposing that a spike in emissions could be justified if it led to new technology that lowered future emissions. This answer demonstrates that the spike is not necessary - emissions are already declining all across the developed world. We don't need new tech, we need to deploy the existing renewable tech in the global south.

Comment: Regardless of how correct your statement is (a spike is not necessary), your reasoning is flawed. You cannot support this conclusion by, first of all looking at the US (the US is a historical anomaly is every regard), and two by looking at a small time frame (20 years). I can find hundreds of counter examples from across thousands of years. And it's easy to even look at countries in isolation (new world vs old world vs Asia).

Comment: @JMS - the number of manufacturing jobs in the US appears completely detached from our CO2 emissions -- manufacturing jobs **declined** from 2000 to 2007, while emissions **increased.** Then the number of manufacturing jobs **increased** from 2010 to 2023, while emissions **decreased!**  -- Source: https://data.bls.gov/pdq/SurveyOutputServlet

Comment: @uberhaxed - European emissions are also decreasing while experiencing GDP growth, so I don't believe the US is particularly exceptional in this regard -- It is possible to expand an economy without increasing CO2 emissions. But I would encourage you to write your own answer if you don't like mine!

Comment: @CodeMonkey,   That's (1) With automation number of jobs aren't directly tied to productivity any longer. (2) Manufacturing only accounts for 18% of US power consumption.  Industry companies accounts for 25% roughly of US energy consumption and the subset of **[manufacturing accounts to 75% of all industrial energy usage](https://www.energy.gov/eere/amo/articles/analysis-finds-decrease-us-manufacturing-energy-consumption)**.    But as I said the US largely has service economy today.

Comment: It depends upon the time frame and geographic you are looking at. A twenty year gap between peak carbon emissions and peak economic production is still a correlation and virtually simultaneous, if you are look at it from a global 500 year perspective. And, of course, energy consumption and carbon generation, are not the same.